# log4j is not logging into file or console

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

My log4j2.properties file look like this

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout    
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Users\\mchandak\\workspace\\Eclipse\\work\\LeadsDedupe\\logFile1.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1024MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

And below is my code:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.*;

public class Main {

private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger( Main.class.getName());
public static void main(String[] list){
    logger.info("LOGGER IS WORKING");
 }
}
```

Code runs smoothly without any error, yet it is not logging anything. My property file looks good to me. I googled a lot but i can't understand the issue with my code.

Comment: Did you initiate log4j with PropertyConfigurator.configure(""); ?

Comment: log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Users\\mchandak\\workspace\\Eclipse\\work\\LeadsDedupe\\logFile1.log should be log4j.appender.file.File=C:\Users\mchandak\workspace\Eclipse\work\LeadsDedupe\logFile1.log, with single bar, not double.

Comment: no i have not, actually i am new to this and i was trying to learn it from some site and they have not mentioned to initiate it

Comment: eclipse suggested to use double bars for path

Comment: Are you using *log4j 1.x* or *log4j 2*? If it is *log4j 2* (as the `log4j2.properties` filename indicates), your config is not correct - see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your properties file is using the log4j-1.x format. The new format is documented here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties

You are not seeing any logging because the default configuration only logs at ERROR level.